# How to remove duplicate text in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have names and email addresses that are repeated within a cell.  Is there a way to just keep unique names and addresses in the cell? For example:

Currently A1=`martha stewart martha stewart ms@site.com ms@site.com ab@site.com`

Desired result A1=`martha stewart ms@site.com ab@site.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=join(" ",unique(split(A1," "),1))
```

Comment: @Patricia please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/someone-answers)

Comment: Good use of the `UNIQUE` function.